# Does MVC4 bundling and mimification do any caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, bundling-and-minification

I would like to use the bundling and mimification features of MVC4 but I am concerned about the mimification. Is it the case that every time there is a request for css and javascript from a client that the bundling/mimification process works. If so then is there not a CPU overhead each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quote](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification):

> Bundling and minification primarily improve the first page request
>   load time. Once a webpage has been requested, the browser caches the
>   assets (JavaScript, CSS and images) so bundling and minification won’t
>   provide any performance boost when requesting the same page, or pages
>   on the same site requesting the same assets.

So the assets will be cached by the browser and not requested on subsequent pages so there will be no performance hit.

Remark: There's a [bug in ASP.NET MVC 4 RC](http://todd-carter.com/post/2012/06/10/mini-me-fication-in-system-web-optimization-rc-is-evil/) which doesn't perform caching at the server side which will hopefully be fixed in the RTM. So when calling the `@Scripts.Render` helper in the view there will be a performance hit everytime.

Comment: Thanks Darin. It was the caching on the server side I was concerned about. Do you think it will use a lot of CPU doing all the mimification each time a request comes in from a client who has not cached the js and css.

Comment: Did you read the article I have linked to? Yes, it will use resources and there will be a slowdown of rendering of the pages which you could easily measure. But as I said it is a bug: something that we can hope will be fixed before the RTM is released so that you can use the bundling and minification without any performance hit.

Comment: Hi - Yes I just read the article now thanks. Does anyone outside of MS have any approximate ideas when RTM will ship?