# Does ASP MVC4 Bundling and Mimification NOW cache the mimified content on the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been reading about mimification and I note that back in June of 2012 there was a similar question and at the time it was stated that there was no server side caching. Is this still the case or is there now some caching?

[Does MVC4 bundling and mimification do any caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048011/does-mvc4-bundling-and-mimification-do-any-caching?rq=1)

Comment: Yes it does, it was only in the RC that it didnt

Comment: also its called "minification"